# Method addObserver must be called on the main thread while click on DatePicker

Tags: android, react-native, datetimepicker

When I'm trying to open the DateTimePicker in my application this method is displayed.

I have used **import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';** for the date picker in the react-native application.
Here is the code for my date field.[image]

```
    state = { 
setDate: new Date(),
        mode: 'date',
        setDateValue: ''}

    <View style={[styles.viewRow, { marginTop: 15 }]}>
       <Text style={[styles.textStyle, { width: '36%' }]} >{R.strings.exp_date}</Text>
       <Text style={[styles.inputTextStyles, { flex: 1, fontSize: R.dimens.largeTextSize }]} onPress={this.showDatepicker}>{this.state.setDateValue}</Text>
     </View>
    {this.state.dialogShowDatePicker ? (
              <DateTimePicker
                value={this.state.setDateValue}
                mode={'date'}
                display={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'spinner' : 'default'}
                is24Hour={true}
                onChange={this.onChange}
    
              />
            ):null}

onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    console.log("event:-", event);
    this.setState({ showDatePicker: false });
    if (event.type == "set") {
        console.log("onChange:" + selectedDate)
        const dateStr = moment(selectedDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
        console.log("converted Date:" + dateStr)
        this.setState({ setDateValue: dateStr });
        this.setState({ setDate: selectedDate });
    }
    if (event.type == "neutralButtonPressed") {
        this.setState({ setDateValue: '' });
        this.setState({ setDate: new Date() });
    }
};
```

Comment: Am also facing the same issue, did it resolved or found any alternative solution for you. Please help me in fixing this.